# change nested Keyed dictionaries into nested lists of just the keys KDB+/Q

Tags: list, dictionary, kdb

I have a (0h) list (named *result*) of keyed dictionaries, keyed on `RIC.

I want to extract the list of RICs for each entry of *result* and store it in a different list that simply has the nested lists of RICs for each index. I need to be able to apply a function to each list of RICs sequentially by index, and can't figure out how to do it since *result* has keyed dictionaries instead of lists (the keyed dictionaries have other columns too, but RIC is the only one I'm interested in)

Sorry if this explanation is poor, but I'm really not sure how to go about this. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a list of keyed tables. Therefore, you can use qSQL to `exec` the RIC column from each:

```
{exec RIC from x}each result
```

Comment: slighly faster option
```
q)\ts:100 {exec RIC from x}'[tab]
214 66176
q)\ts:100 '[@[;`RIC];key]'[tab]
160 66048
```

Comment: A table is a list of *like* dictionaries; i.e. the keys all match. Here the type of the list is 0, so it is not a table but a list of *unlike* dictionaries, and the expression `'[@[;`RIC];key]'[tab]`, which works for a table, signals a type error.

Comment: good point, missed that in the above cheers

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of keyed dictionaries. Its type is 0, so we know the dictionary keys vary.

[Index At](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/apply/##apply-at-index-at) [Each](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#each) is all you need:

```
q)show dd:(`one`two`three`four`five,'`RIC)!'(`bar;)each(2+5?5)?'`3
`one`RIC!(`bar;`oco`khd`dga`eob)
`two`RIC!(`bar;`iog`edg`kio)
`three`RIC!(`bar;`gme`iko`cje`ijj)
`four`RIC!(`bar;`dlm`klp`epj`bji`gph)
`five`RIC!(`bar;`lfm`mci`pal`eho`kgi`enf)
q)type dd
0h
q)dd@'`RIC
`oco`khd`dga`eob
`iog`edg`kio
`gme`iko`cje`ijj
`dlm`klp`epj`bji`gph
`lfm`mci`pal`eho`kgi`enf

q)(dd@'`RIC) ~ {exec RIC from x}each dd
1b
q)\ts:10000 {exec RIC from x}each dd
18 1456
q)\ts:10000 dd@'`RIC
5 736
```

(Will also work with a list of keyed tables.)